# JQuery - How to find whether all the images are loaded from an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I updates a div content with some html via an ajax call, and I what to execute a function after all the images from the ajax response are loaded.

See the code below, `#gridWrapper` is coming from the Ajax response and it has a lot of thumbnail images.

```
success: function(Data){
 MyGrid.prepGridLayout(Data.html);
 $('#gridWrapper .thumbnail img').load(function(index) {
  MyGrid.updateCellWidth(this);
 });
 MyGrid.adjustGridWidth();
 MyGrid.animateGridLayout();
}
```

I need to execute the `MyGrid.animateGridLayout();` only after all images are loaded. Currently `MyGrid.animateGridLayout();` is executed before `MyGrid.updateCellWidth(this);` executes

How to make sure the `MyGrid.animateGridLayout();` runs only after all images are loaded ?

Comment: i don't know, but as an alternative you can pre-load these images and then on ajax complete (of html) do animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the "load" handlers keep track of how many they've done.

```
success: function(Data){
  MyGrid.prepGridLayout(Data.html);
  var thumbs = $('#gridWrapper .thumbnail img'), tc = 0;
  thumbs.load(function(index) {
    MyGrid.updateCellWidth(this);
    if (++tc === thumbs.length) {
      MyGrid.adjustGridWidth();
      MyGrid.animateGridLayout();
    }
   });
}
```